# How to call the a predefined function on click of a context menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, firefox, firefox-addon

I have added a context menu item on a page for my add-on. On click of this context menu item i want one of my predefined function to be executed but am unable to figure out a way for it

This is the code for context menu

```
var contextMenu = require("sdk/context-menu");
var menuItem = contextMenu.Item({
  label: "Log Selection",
  contentScript: 'self.on("click", onClick);',
});

function onClick(state) {
//This function calls many other functions thus can not be defined locally
            console.log("onClick() called");
}
```

assuming that there is a `function onClick()` which needs to be called on click of the context menu. How to call `onClick()` function?

Comment: Use `oncommand` with menu items, its nicer as it responds to keyboard as well.

Comment: @Noitidart I didn't get you please explain little more.

Comment: I'm not so sure of this myself this is an sdk specfic question i think. I just know that onCommand is the preferred method to use, but an sdk dev will have to reply to you on the rest :(

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.  Modified from my extension which returns information on the clicked node.

```
function unassignUSER(upChange) {
    console.log("onClick() called");
}

var contextMenu = require("sdk/context-menu");
var menuItem = contextMenu.Item({
    label: "Log Selection",
    contentScript: 'self.on("click", function (node) {' +
                 '  var upChange = "data"' +
                 '  self.postMessage(upChange);' +
                 '});',
    onMessage: function (upChange) {
        unassignUSER(upChange);
    }
});
```